# react virtualized and InfiniteLoader

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I have the following sandBox https://codesandbox.io/s/mqk1z565qp with a custom implementation of `react-virtualized` using `Table` and `InfiniteLoader` components inspired by official documentation and examples. https://github.com/bvaughn/reactvirtualized/blob/master/docs/InfiniteLoader.md

but I am driving nuts when adding InfiniteLoader.

I need help from the community what is wrong with the current implementation and to help me to move forward.

In the current stand point initial data is not properly rendered. Only some of them are rendered... The expectation is that the first 50 batch of users are displayed with any interaction from user end. Why it is not happening right now?

Secondly when user scrolls down in some point a request should be done to the server for requesting next batch of rows (50 more). Right now, when user scrolls the example behaves wrongly.

As I understand from the documentation for each row a request is send to the server with a given startIndex / stopIndex.

Regarding this In a later stage have 2 thoughts pending to implement.

- Reduce the number of request to the server. ideally only when scrolling is close to reach the bottom ask for next batch.
- Translate from startIndex / stopIndex to a page param. My real API endpoint is the param that expects and not startIndex / stopIndex!

But for now I am happy enough having a scrollable table and loading data on demand through `InfiniteLoader`

note: I have a data.js. It fakes a resultset of data split in 3 pages.

Comment: have you found a solution for this? I'm dealing with the exact same situation. I'm not sure if I can handle it with infiniteLoader or just virtualizedTable.